# WSO2 API Manager - Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm seeing below error in WSO2 API Manager 1.6 after running the `wso2server.sh` for sometime with average load. I got below error repeatedly on the error log.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
        ... 13 more
[2015-03-03 22:50:48,527]  INFO - ReceiverGroup Resending the failed events....
[2015-03-03 22:50:48,527] ERROR - EventPublisher Cannot send events to TCP,localhost:7612,TCP,localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.EventPublisherException: Cannot send Events
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.ThriftEventPublisher.publish(ThriftEventPublisher.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher.publishEvent(EventPublisher.java:130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher.run(EventPublisher.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_publish(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.publish(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:133)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.ThriftEventPublisher.publish(ThriftEventPublisher.java:86)
        ... 5 more
```

What could be the reason and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that you have enabled publishing runtime statistics to BAM. From the log i can see that the server is trying to publish to "TCP,localhost:7612,TCP,localhost:7712" which would be thrift ports. So if you don't have a BAM server running with thrift port 7612 this error would come. You can find more information on publishing runtime statistics to BAM here [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Comment: Yes I have configured BAM and it's running without an issue.

Comment: Yeah I ran out of space. That's the reason.